# Script timeouts while trying to add large amount of rows

Tags: cakephp, timeout

I'm trying to add a large amount of records into my database using `cakephp` (for a QR Code linking system).

My base code goes like this:

```
public function generateQrCodes($program_id = null, $amount = 10000)
    {
        //add entries into database & generate QR images
        for ($i = 1; $i++; $i <= $amount) {
            $this->_createQr($program_id, $i);
        }

        //generate ZIP file
    }

    private function _createQr($program_id, $number)
    {
        //save into database
        $this->create();
        $this->data['Qrcode']['program_id'] = $program_id;
        $this->data['Qrcode']['qr'] = $number;
        $saved = $this->save();

        if ($saved) {
            $this->_createQrImage($program_id, $number);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Obviously this times out (after about 900ish rows). Can someone help me work out a way to rewrite this so that it wont timeout (break it into chunks somehow)?

Answer (score 1):

How long it takes to : $this->_createQrImage($program_id, $number); ?

You could probably do this in a shell so it will not timeout..

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1107/Creating-Shells-Tasks

Comment: I think the issue is that it is timing out on the generateQrCodes method on the for loop there...

Currently that _createQrImage method isnt doing anything at all really.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can modify the max_execution_time directive in php.ini to a larger value.  It's default time is 30 seconds.  If you don't have access to the main php.ini such as you are on shared hosting then you can create a local copy of php.ini in your own directories and it will allow you to override those directives that you need to change.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Comment: Thats a bit of a cheap work around, I dont really want to do that...

The app is hosted on a VPS so i have full access to the php.ini file... 

Would be good if I could work out a way so that you click a button, and the generateQrCodes method is run in the background.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a cheap workaround.  That directive was put in there for a reason so you can adjust the time based on the needs of your application.  To run in the background you would probably want to use a cron job (Linux, Unix) platform or task scheduler (Windows) platform to execute your PHP script but you are still going to run into time limits.

Comment: You could also use the exec command but there are a few things you have to do with that to make sure your script doesn't just hang.  But again you will run into time limits. http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php